# Content of innerHTML is "undefined"

Tags: javascript, php

I never had this problem before, but now working with PHP when I try to edit the content of a div with the id of a product taken directly from it's id in the database like this (both separaed in two foreach getting their current correct IDs) because I need them separated so when I can change the content, I can modify it so I can make the second DIV display: none by default and after clicking the first one making it display: inline:

```
<div id="h<?php echo $obra['id'] ?>" onClick="display()"> </div> // Getting ID h + 84 (h84) this time
<div id="<?php echo $obra['id'] ?>"> TEST TEXT</div> // Getting ID 84 this time)
```

And the function is:

```
function display() {
    var result = document.getElementById("84").innerHTML;
    result.innerHTML = "test";
    alert(result);
}
```

Now, when I click the first DIV, it should get the content of the div with ID 84, which is "TEST TEXT", and then change it for "test" and change the content which I see in the browser and after that, alert with the new result value, but the content doesn't change and the alert shows me TEST TEXT.

Here is the full relevant code if needed:

```
<div class="row m-0">
            <div class="accordion pl-0 col-4 text-center">
        <?php   if ( count($cuadros) == 0) { ?>
                    <p class="text-center mt-3">No hay cuadros registrados.</p>
        <?php   } else { 
                    $cont = 0;
                        foreach ( $cuadros as $obra ) { ?>
                            <div class="card border-top-0 border-left-0 rounded-0 p-0">
                                <div class="card-header border-0" id="h<?php echo $obra['id'] /* it gets value "84" */ ?>" onClick="display()">
                                    <h5 class="mb-0">
        <?php                           echo $obra['nombreObras']; ?>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
        <?php       $cont++; } ?>
            </div>
        <?php foreach ( $cuadros as $obra ) { ?>
            <div class="col-4 hidden" id="<?php echo $obra['id'] /* It gets value "84" */ ?>">
                TEST TEXT
            </div>
        <?php   } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

And a screenshot of what happens (note that the change should be reflected in the alert, **which is not**)
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: I recommend moving away from inline js / css - it's bad practice leads to hard-to maintain code

Comment: why you are doing two times `innerHTML`?

Comment: Look at your code closely
`var result = document.getElementById("84").innerHTML;
 result.innerHTML = "test";`

Comment: How should I do it, then? I am willing to learn how to use jQuery and Listeners, but I only worked with inline JS at school, so I'm not used to it.

Comment: @B.Desai I was doing it to see if I coult get the actual value of the second ID (which it returned me correctly).
epascarello Yeah, I didn't know that getting the content with innerHTML would give me trouble.

Comment: @pete I believe OP actually wants `"test"` in the alert.. He is extending the results.innerHTML to contain an innerHTML.. innerHTMLception.

Comment: @Pogrindis Sorry I realised just after I posted the comment, thought I'd deleted it fast enough!

Comment: @JavierGreen that sucks to hear, school teaching people to code wrong :/ use external .js files and call in via `<script src="/path/to/script/js></script>"`

Comment: Yes, that was what I wanted. I used the first innerHTMl to just get the actual content and the second one to actually modify it. @ThisGuyHasTwoThumgs Yeah, that's what I do, but I guess, school teaches badly, or what it teaches is just an introduction to what actually JS is. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are performing `innerHTML` agin. So it will return error. Remove `innerHTML` from result

```
function display() {
    var result = document.getElementById("84");
    result.innerHTML = "test";
    alert(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it! How I am supposed to get the content if not with innerHTML? Thank you again.